# How do I make one word in a text box end a program?

Tags: c#, string, exit

So one of the forms I have to create is where you enter a first and last name and then it splits the two names and puts them next to the appropriate labels, form design: https://gyazo.com/9b34dca0c1cd464fd865830390fcb743 but when the word stop is entered in any way e.g. Stop, StOp, sToP etc. it needs to end.

```
        private void btnSeparate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strfullname, strgivenname, strfamilyname, strfirstname;
        int int_space_location_one, int_space_location_two;

        strfullname = txtFullName.Text;


        int_space_location_one = strfullname.IndexOf(" ");
        strgivenname = strfullname.Substring(0, int_space_location_one);


        lblGivenEntered.Text = strgivenname;


        strfirstname = strfullname.Remove(0, int_space_location_one + 1);
        int_space_location_two = strfirstname.IndexOf(" ");


        strfamilyname = strfirstname.Substring(int_space_location_two + 1);
        lblFamilyEntered.Text = strfamilyname;
    }
```

This is my current code, I have tried many different ways to get the word stop to end it but it wont work so that's why there is currently no code trying to stop the program, the main problem I get is because it is searching for a space between the first and last name and it obviously doesn't have one for one word it just crashes.

Any help with this would be amazing, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be doing some error handling or checking to make sure that those operations aren't going to cause an unhandled exception. Otherwise, you just need to check the text in the textbox for 'stop' and then terminate the program if it is found.

Comment: By checking for 'magic words' before checking for the space, you can return from the method as before performing the space-check.

Somehow this feels a bit like a homework assignment...

Comment: You may need to tokenize the string, not just "contains", unless you're okay with a last name like deststoppo or whatever making the program quit...

Comment: @RickvandenBosch it's not homework it's just general week to week work but my lecturer isn't in and hasn't been for the last few weeks and there isn't anyone else to help so I have been on this site looking for help for a couple weeks whenever I get stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hook up the `TextChanged` event and go like this:

```
private void TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If text, converted to lower-characters contains "stop" -> Exit
    if(txtFullName.Text.ToLower().Contains("stop"))
    {
        // What I understand as "stopping it".
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

**IF** with "stop it" you mean to cancle the operation:

```
private void btnSeparate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If text, converted to lower-characters contains "stop" -> Exit
    if (txtFullName.Text.ToLower().Contains("stop"))
    {
        // What I understand as "stopping it".
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code inside the else block
    }
}
```

---

**Short version of everything:** *Also covering `no spaces` problem*

```
private void btnSeparate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save how many words are inside
    int wordsInText = txtFullName.Text.Split(' ').Length;
    // Save if "stop" was typed into the textbox
    bool stopExisting = !txtFullName.Text.ToLower().Contains("stop");

    // If text has exactly 3 words and "stop" is NOT existing
    if (wordsInText == 3 && !stopExisting)
    {
        // Save array of splitted parts
        string[] nameParts = txtFullName.Text.Split(' ');

        // This is never used??
        string strfirstname = nameParts[1];

        // Set name-parts to labels
        lblGivenEntered.Text = nameParts[0];
        lblFamilyEntered.Text = nameParts[2];
    }
    // If text has NOT exactly 3 words and "stop" is NOT existing
    else if(wordsInText != 3 && !stopExisting)
    {
        // If there are no 3 words, handle it here - MessageBox?
    }
    // If "stop" IS existing
    else if(stopExisting)
    {
        // If text contains "stop" handle it here
        // Application.Exit(); <-- if you really want to exit
    }
}
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it's unclear if it should end as soon as they type "stop" or after they hit the button. If it's done after they click the button, some checking for "stop" first in `btnSeparate_Click()` would work fine.

Comment: @Frecklefoot You are right. Appended different versions.

Comment: @ASI Check my last edit (very bottom). Also if this solved your problem, consider marking it as solved (hook right below the voting-buttons). Your welcome ;).

Comment: @ASI As this is a question about the very basics I've added comments to clarify whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check, if one of the entered words is equal to the word "stop". There you need a StringComparions which ignores the case. Or you could parse the entered word into lower/upper-cases.

So if the check is true, you could just end the program with

`Environment.Exit(0);`

You could just check, if one of the entered words is equal to the word "stop". There you need a StringComparions which ignores the case. Or you could parse the entered word into lower/upper-cases.

So if the check is true, you could just end the program with

`Environment.Exit(0);`

Code:

```
if (strfullname.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("stop"))
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```